# Блоки DIV по горизонтали

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

```
<div id="main">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Нужно отобразить блоки `#main div` по горизонтали, так, чтобы не переносились на новую строку, если достигли предела ширину блока `#main`.

Пробовал `float:left; display:inline-block;`

Comment: а можно поподробнее о условиях? если есть возможность, можно задать ширину в которую помещаются блоки, ну или вариант задать ширину для div в процентах 

Comment: Ширина же задана для #main, когда вложенные блоки div достигают предела ширину в 1119px блок спозлает снизу и в левый край.

Comment: попробуй div{width:33%;}

Comment: и что это даст? у меня количество блоков вложенных не обязательно 3

Comment: #main{display:table;} div{display:table-cell}

Comment: Нужно, чтобы они скрывались или меняли размер?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nb6Wv/ посмотрите такой вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    html, body{
        height: 100%;
    }
    body{
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    div {
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        margin:10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #main{
        width: 1119px;
        height: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #main>div{
        width: 150px;
        height: 120px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
```

[Пример](http://sinsite.ru/temp2.php)

Comment: Вы плохо прочитали мой вопрос, сейчас это сделано, но это не решает проблему. Добавьте в ваш пример по ссылке - еще 5 блоков и проиндексируйте - увидите, что не поместившиеся блоки съехали в невидимую область слева.

Answer (score 0):

не проще ли для всех троих блоков задать ширину и высоту а потом просто добавит ко всем `float:left`

Answer (score 0):

Очень легко: блокам **display: inline-block;** родителю **white-space: nowrap;**. Таким образом мы запрещаем перенос строк.

Answer (score 0):

## Решение без переноса:

```css
.main
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.main__item
{
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main">
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
</div>
```

## Решение с переносом:

```css
.main
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main__item
{
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main">
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
</div>
```

## Кроссбраузерность без переноса:

upd: с переносом думаю сами додуматесь? :)

```css
.main
{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.main__item
{
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main">
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
  <div class="main__item">Вася</div>
  <div class="main__item">Петя</div>
  <div class="main__item">Миша</div>
  <div class="main__item">Сыр</div>
</div>
```